# Why is the Exception not printing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

In the REPL, I can print the string representation of an exception:

```
>>> print(str(ValueError))
<class 'ValueError'>
>>> print(ValueError)
<class 'ValueError'>
```

In this simple code, the value is not printing. What am I missing?

**First flavor:**

```
try:
    raise ValueError
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    print('We crashed!')
```

This just outputs *We crashed!*

The second flavor outputs the same. What happened to `print(str(e))`?

**Second flavor:**

```
def crash():
    raise ValueError

try:
    crash()
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    print('We crashed!')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the REPL, I can print the string representation of an exception:
>
> ```
> >>> print(str(ValueError))
> <class 'ValueError'>
> ```

No, you're printing the string representation of an exception *class*. When you do

```
raise ValueError
```

`ValueError` isn't actually the exception object that gets raised. Python implicitly raises `ValueError()` instead, and the `str` of *that* is empty.

Answer (score 7):

It does print the exception message, but you have to look closely:

```
>>> def crash():
...     raise ValueError
>>> try:
...     crash()
... except Exception as e:
...     print(str(e))
...     print('We crashed!')

We crashed!
```

The empty line in front of "We crashed" is the error message (empty string) you supplied when doing `raise ValueError`. To have the representation of your exceptions use `repr` instead of `str`:

```
>>> try:
...     crash()
... except Exception as e:
...     print(repr(e))
...     print('We crashed!')
ValueError()
We crashed!
```

Note that [`raise ValueError` is just a shorthand for `raise ValueError()`](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions) (note the paranthesis).

Comment: The four answers complete each other so it was hard to pick one. +1 and thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're not supplying any args to the instance that is eventually created, there's nothing to print.

Supply the message that will eventually get printed out by initializing and supplying it as an argument:

```
try:
    raise ValueError("What value error?")
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    print('We crashed!')
What value error?
We crashed!
```

Also, though I know this is just a demonstration, I am obliged to point out that using `Exception` as the target in your handlers is bad practice :-)

Comment: The four answers complete each other so it was hard to pick one. +1 and thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

As in user2357112 's answer in your except block your are trying  to print an instance of ValueError not the ValueError class. If you want  to print the class try something like below.

```
try:
    raise ValueError
except Exception as e:
    print(e.__class__)
    print('We crashed!')
```

Comment: The four answers complete each other so it was hard to pick one. +1 and thank you. :)